# Bash regex finding and replacing

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I don't know if this is possible, but can you dynamically alter a find/replace?
Basically I have something like this

```
<3 digit number> <data>
```

and what I want to do is if data matches the pattern

```
<word>:<4 digit number>
```

replace all instances (in the entire file) of `<word>:` with the line's 3 digit number I.E:

```
020 Word
021 Word:0001
Replace with 
020 021
021 0210001
```

Is this doable with AWK or Sed?
If not, is it doable in C?

Comment: So, tell me if I've got this right: if one line is `021 Hello:1234`, then you want all instances of `Hello:` in the entire file replaced with `021`? But **not** if it was, for example, `021 Hello:123`?

Comment: can a file contain more than one Word:0001 pattern and the previous numbers are different? e.g. 055 Word:0001 and 056 Word:0002?

Comment: I think that swiss' got the closest to what I need but I can't seem to get it to run right.  "Word" is not a specfic thing, just an example.  Basically the word is a line label and I want to replace all instances of the line label with the line's number.  There can be multiple labels on various lines throughout the program and multiple references to those labels.

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't what you asked, but I think the best way to solve this is with a simple Perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$in= "input.txt";
$out= "output.txt";

# Buffer the whole file for replacing:
open(INFILE, $in);
@lines = <INFILE>;
open(INFILE, $in);

# Iterate through each line:
while(<INFILE>) {
  # If the line matches "word:number", replace all instances in the file
  if (/^(\d{3}) (\w+:)\d{4}$/) {
    $num = $1; word = $2;
    s/$word/$num/ foreach @lines;
  }
}

open(OUTFILE, $out);
print OUTFILE foreach @lines;
```

It looks a lot longer than it really needs to be, because I made it nice and easy-to-read for you.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this time I got you right.

try the stuff below:

```
#file name:t
kent$  cat t
020 Word
021 Word:0001

#first we find out the replacement, 021 in this case:
kent$  v=$(grep -oP "(\d{3})(?= Word:\d{4})" t|head -n1)

#do replace by sed:
kent$  sed -r "s/Word[:]?/$v/g" t                                                                                                        
020 021 
021 0210001
```

Answer (score 2):

```
number=$(gawk --posix '/[0-9]{3} '${word}':[0-9]{4}/ { print $1; exit }' $file)

if [ "$number" != "" ]; then
    sed -r "s/${word}:?/${number}/" $file
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

This awk solution takes 2 passes through your file: once to find all the `Word`s needing replacement, and once to actually do the replacing:

```
gawk '
    NR == FNR {
        if (match($2, /^([^:]+):[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/, a)) 
            repl[a[1] ":?"] = $1
        next
    }
    {
        for (word in repl)
            if ($2 ~ word) {
                sub(word, repl[word], $2)
                break
            }
        print
    }
' filename filename > new.file
```

Requires `gawk` for capturing parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another sed solution:

```
# sweep the file and make a lookup table variable

lookup=$(sed -nr 's/(.*) (.*:).*/\2\1/p' <source_file |tr '\n' ' ')

# append the lookup to each line and substitute using a backreference
# N.B. remove the lookup whatever!

     sed -r "s/\$/@@${lookup}/;
             s/^(... )(.*)$@@.*\2:(\S*).*/\1\3/;
             s/^(... )(.*:)(.*)@@.*\2(\S*).*/\1\4\3/;
             s/@@.*//" <source_file
```